# How to synchronize 2 bare repositories in Gitolite?

Tags: gitolite

I have a following requirement,two remote bare repositories repository A and repository B and my aim is to sync or push `repoA` contents to `repoB` @regular intervals.

I use Gitolite v3 btw, should I go for Gitolite mirroring or post-receive hooks? if its a post-receive, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly adding a post-receive hook (see "[(v3.6+) variation: repo-specific hooks](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#v3.6-variation-repo-specific-hooks)") is the easiest way.

```
cd /path/to/your/gitolite-admin-clone
mkdir -p local/hooks/repoA

git push --mirror ../repoB
```

**[Mirroring](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#mirroring)** is mainly for synchronization between different gitolite servers (I suppose it could be setup to mirror on the same server as in [`t/mirror-test`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/t/mirror-test), but that it a bit overkill).
Plus it adds:

> From v3.5.3 on, gitolite uses an **asynchronous push to the slaves**, so that the main push returns immediately, without waiting for the slave pushes to complete.
>   Keep this in mind if you're writing scripts that do a push, and then read one of the slaves immediately -- you will need to add a few seconds of sleep in your script.

That means:

If you have *multiple* gitolite servers to maintain, then mirroring is interesting, mainly because the `push --mirror` is done asynchronously from the initial `git push` to repoA.
In that aspect, gitolite mirroring is quicker, because you push to A, and in the background, gitolite will `push --mirror` to other gitolite servers.

But here, for just one other repo (on the same gitolite server, or on another gitolite server), a simple post-receive hook is enough.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I'm looking for :) .. Thanks much.

Comment: just a curious thought, in case if there are 2 gitolite servers(bare repos) say A & B , will post-receive hook still be effective as u suggested?

Comment: @VoC: What if in case there are 2 gitolite servers(bare repos) say A & B , will post-receive hook still be effective as u suggested or I should go for gitolite mirroring..

Comment: @Vigs no, you can keep the post-receive option: the answer is made for 2 bare repos on gitolite. One with a post-receive hook, which pushes --mirror to the other repo. If that other repo is on another gitolite server, that would still work.

Comment: @Vigs if you have *multiple* gitolite servers to maintain, *then* mirroring is interesting, mainly because the `push --mirror` is done **asynchronously** from the initial `git push` to repoA. In that aspect, gitolite mirroring is quicker, because you push to A, and in the background, gitolite will `push --mirror` to other gitolite servers.

Comment: Thanks much for the perfect explanation

Comment: @Vigs I have included that explanation in the answer for more visibility.