# Giltolite cloning from the slave end

Tags: gitolite

In my project I have two Gitolite instances, installed on 2 servers, say location `A` & location `B`.
Repository at location `A` is the `master` and repo at B is the slave.

My requirement is like: my project team members at location `B` should be able to clone from the slave gitolite instance(at location `B`) directly.
Is it possible ? If so how?

(I'm here concerned about a single repository say `TEST` at both the locations)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that:

- the access rules for that git repo is duplicated between the two `gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf` files of the two gitolite server
- the users have their public ssh keys registered in both server `gitolite-admin/keys` folders

Those users should then be able to clone that single repo from B.
You might want to consider [hook or mirroring in order to synchronize that repos between the two servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256812/6309) though.

Comment: Link shared was very useful , will implement, test and will update my post.Thanks for your inputs